# Python code to Open multiple path and run .cmd file for specific period

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, automation, command-prompt

I'm trying to run multiple run.cmd file which will run for different time, consider run1 file will run  for 40 seconds , and run2 file will run for 20 seconds and run3 file will run for  30 seconds. so what i need is a program to open multiple path where these run files are there
to and run those files for specific period of time.

I have tried some python code but im not getting desired output.

please find the code below

```
import os 
# list of folder paths to
folders = [ r"C:\path\run1.cmd fast", 
            r"C:\path\run2.cmd fast",                  
            r"C:\path\run3.cmd fast"]  

for folder in folders:    
   os.system(folder)    
   time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Should your python script end the cmd files after a given period of time? Or do you just want to set the starting points. cmd 1 after 10 s, cmd 2 after 30s and so on?

Comment: my python script should open and run the cmd file until it ends its execution!! for example cmd1 will take 30s then it should end and should open other cmdfile

Comment: import subprocess

subprocess.call("dir", shell=True)
subprocess.call("c:\git\intrep_AIR20\gitPull.exe")

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

# Set the parent directory
parent_directory = '/path/to/parent/directory/'

# Loop through each subdirectory within the parent directory
for subdirectory in os.listdir(parent_directory):

    # Create the full path for the subdirectory
    subdirectory_path = os.path.join(parent_directory, subdirectory)

    # Check if the subdirectory is a directory (and not a file)
    if os.path.isdir(subdirectory_path):

        # Navigate to the subdirectory
        os.chdir(subdirectory_path)

        # Run the .bat file within the subdirectory
        os.system('start my_script.bat')

        # Navigate back to the parent directory
        os.chdir(parent_directory)
```

tried same thing for .bat file